# How to show multiple customised google maps on a single page?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, jsp, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I need to show coordinates of multiple items on separate maps on a single page.

To accomplish this I need to do something similar to the code below. The question is how to pass the list of map names and coordinates to JavaScript?

values I can pass are following three values

```
    ${location.lat}
    ${location.long}
    ${location.mapName}
```

JSP

I loop through the list to show the name of each location, I am also trying to set the id of each map different to the other.

```
<c:forEach var="location" items="${locations}">
    <div id="item">
          <h1>${location.name}</h1>
          <div id="${location.mapName}"></div>      
    </div>
</c:forEach>

<script>
...
var myOptions = {
    zoom: 14,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(0.0, 0.0),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
                                myOptions);

    map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas2"),
                                   myOptions);  
}

</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off all, since `Location` is a java object you can't have an attribute called `long`. Also, `<div id="item">` insede the `forEach` will generate objects with duplicated ids on DOM.

For the test, I created a `Location` object like this:

```java
public class Location {

    private double lat;
    private double lng;
    private String mapName;

    private String name;

    // getters and setters

}
```

In a simple way, just iterate over `locations` to cread the location to the maps, like this:

```jsp
<c:forEach var="location" items="${locations}">
    <h5>${location.name}</h5>
    <div id="${location.mapName}" style="height: 180px; width: 400px;"></div>
</c:forEach>
```

And iterate to generate the map objects, markers and whatever, like this:

```
<c:forEach var="location" items="${locations}">
    var latLng_${location.mapName} = new gm.LatLng(${location.lat}, ${location.lng});
    var options_${location.mapName} = {
        zoom: 14,
        center: latLng_${location.mapName},
        mapTypeId: gm.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    };

    var ${location.mapName} = new gm.Map(document.getElementById("${location.mapName}"), options_${location.mapName});

    var marker_${location.mapName} = new gm.Marker({
        title: "${location.name}",
        position: latLng_${location.mapName},
        map: ${location.mapName}
    });
</c:forEach>
```

You can enclose this in a function if you want to. In a test I generated 4 maps, like in this image:

[image: Test with multiple maps]

This is the entire JSP:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var gm = google.maps;
    function initialize() {
    <c:forEach var="location" items="${locations}">
        var latLng_${location.mapName} = new gm.LatLng(${location.lat}, ${location.lng});
        var options_${location.mapName} = {
            zoom: 14,
            center: latLng_${location.mapName},
            mapTypeId: gm.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
        };

        var ${location.mapName} = new gm.Map(document.getElementById("${location.mapName}"), options_${location.mapName});

        var marker_${location.mapName} = new gm.Marker({
            title: "${location.name}",
            position: latLng_${location.mapName},
            map: ${location.mapName}
        });
    </c:forEach>
    }

    gm.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<c:forEach var="location" items="${locations}">
    <h5>${location.name}</h5>
    <div id="${location.mapName}" style="height: 180px; width: 400px;"></div>
</c:forEach>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks mate I will try that, would you please have a look at this question as well, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29982289/how-to-show-items-on-google-map-similar-to-the-way-google-shows-its-results

Comment: @DanielNewtown OK, I see as soon as possible.

Comment: I am working on the code it shows error message on </c:forEach> "Syntax error on token(s), misplaced 
 construct(s)"

Comment: @DanielNewtown Did you modified the code or are testing as shown in this answer?

Comment: As is, but shows the error, Ive just found out it ignores the errors but does not find the element.

Comment: In your servlet (or whatever), are you setting `locations` with a list of object like `Location`?

Comment: yeah it has the correct name but the div of map is insider other divs, when I remove those divs it works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76792/discussion-between-daniel-newtown-and-bruno-cesar).

Answer (score 0):

The key to achieving what you want is to realize that you need multiple contexts/optionsets declared, one for each map.  My personal approach would be to define an initialization function that takes your values as parameters like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var maps = [];
     function InitMap(latitude,longitude,container) {
          var myOptions = {
              zoom: 14,
              center: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
          }
          maps.push(
              new google.maps.Map(
                  document.getElementById(container),
                  myOptions)
          );
     }
</script>

<c:forEach var="location" items="${locations}">
    <div id="item">
      <h1>${location.name}</h1>
      <div id="${location.mapName}"></div> 
      <script type="text/javascript">
          InitMap(${location.lat}, ${location.long}, '${location.mapName}');
      </script>
   </div>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: It does not work, I also did what is suggested here but it did not work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22621516/calling-jquery-function-from-jstl-cforeach-function-not-defined-on-page-load

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution :3 ... I hope this help.

```
<script>
function insertMarker(lat, lng, mapname){
var myOptions = {
    zoom: 14,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
    "map_"+ mapname = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(mapname),
                                myOptions);    
}
}
</script>

<c:forEach var="location" items="${locations}">

    <div id="item">
          <h1>${location.name}</h1>
          <div id="${location.mapName}"></div>      
    </div>
    <script>
         insertMarker(0.0, 0.0, "<%=location.mapName%>");
    </script>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: The issue is it prints the body of the loop for many times is there any way to avoid it?

Comment: I also did what is suggested here but it did not work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22621516/calling-jquery-function-from-jstl-cforeach-function-not-defined-on-page-load